# boost::asio with SSL - problems after SSL error

Tags: c++, boost, openssl, boost-asio

I use synchronous boost::asio SSL sockets in my application. I initialize all parameters and then connect to some hosts (one after another) and do a GET request for each host.

Everything works until I get a "404 - Not Found" error for one of the hosts. After this error, all new connections fail with some unspecified SSL error.

Do I have to reset the ssl::stream somehow? Is it possible to re-initialize the ssl::stream after each connection?

In the following code snippets I removed error handling and all non asio related things.

**Main:**

```
asio::io_service ioservice;
asio::ssl::context ctx(ioservice, asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
ctx.set_verify_mode(asio::ssl::context::verify_none);

Connector *con = new Connector(ioservice, ctx);

while (!iplist.empty())
{
    ...
    con->ssl_connect(ipaddress, port);
    ...
}
```

**Connector:**

```
Connector::Connector(asio::io_service& io_service, asio::ssl::context &ctx) 
    : sslSock(io_service, ctx)
{
}

Connector::ssl_connect(std::string ipAdr, std::string port)
{
    ...
    tcp::resolver resolver(ioserv);
    tcp::resolver::query query(ipAdr, port);
    endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    ...

    asio::error_code errorcode = asio::error::host_not_found;
    tcp::resolver::iterator end;

    // Establish connection
    while (errorcode && endpoint_iterator != end)
    {
        sslSock.lowest_layer().close();
        sslSock.lowest_layer().connect(*endpoint_iterator++, errorcode);
    }
    sslSock.handshake(asio::ssl::stream_base::client, errorcode);
    ...
    asio::write(...);
    ...
    asio::read(...);
    ...
    sslSock.lowest_layer().close();
    ...
    return;
}
```

Comment: "some unspecified SSL error" is not very useful information.  OpenSSL supplies very good error messages, if you care to check them (eg. `ERR_print_errors_fp()`).

Comment: @caf - Thank you for the info. Asio only writes "SSL error". I will check if OpenSSL has more infos

Comment: @Sam Miller: Yes, I have handlers for all return codes and exceptions.

Comment: @caf: How can I access the detailed openssl errors from via asio? Is there a special function? asio returns only "ssl error"...

Comment: @mspoerr: I haven't used asio, but if it is using OpenSSL underneath, then you should be able to `#include <openssl/err.h>` and `<stdio.h>`, then use `ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);` to print the error stack to `stderr`.

Comment: where does the `error 404 not found` come from? `connect`, `resolver`,  `handshake`?

Comment: the 404 error is in the received data stream (asio::read())

Comment: Regarding the SSL error output: I was not able to get more information...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer from the asio mailing list (many thanks to Marsh Ray). Sam Miller was correct in that the asio::ssl::context has to be created each time. To achieve this, `std::auto_ptr` is used.

Connector.h:

```
std::auto_ptr<asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>> sslSock;
```

Connector.cpp:

```
asio::ssl::context ctx(ioserv, asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
ctx.set_verify_mode(asio::ssl::context::verify_none);
sslSock.reset(new asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>(ioserv, ctx));
```

Answer (score 4):

you might try recreating the `asio::ssl::context` each time you create a `asio::ssl::stream`.

Comment: I am not sure how I can do this. There is no option to assign the context after creating the socket.

Comment: @mspoerr you would instantiate the socket as well.

Comment: This would be very complicated, because it means a complete redesign of my application. I need to think about it...

Comment: I added a bounty, because maybe there is a better option to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same exception because I ran `curl_global_cleanup();` before I was done with curl in the application.